# No value accessor for form control with

Tags: angular, nativescript

Вообщем пишу приложение ну точнее переписываю html, ну не важно и вот такая ошибка `ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'password'` в консоли, само приложение запускается, но обработчик поля не робит. Вот вид:

```
<StackLayout class="nt-form" [formGroup]="signForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signForm.value)">
  <StackLayout class="nt-input">
    <Label text="{{ 'Email' | translate }}" class="nt-label"></Label>
    <TextField required hint="{{ 'Email' | translate }}" formControlName="email" keyboardType="email" text="">
    </TextField>
    <Label class="mat-error" *ngIf="checkError('email')" text="{{ getErrors('email') }}">
    </Label>
  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout class="nt-input">
    <Label text="{{ 'Password' | translate }}" class="nt-label"></Label>
    <TextField required hint="{{ 'Password' | translate }}" formControlName="password" secure="true" text="">
    </TextField>
    <Label class="mat-error" *ngIf="checkError('password')" text="{{ getErrors('password') }}"></Label>
  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout class="nt-input">
    <Button type="submit" [disabled]="!signForm.valid" text="{{ 'Sign in' | translate }}"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
<ActivityIndicator [busy]="isBusy"></ActivityIndicator>
</StackLayout>
```

Вот код ts:

```
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {
  isBusy: boolean = true;

  signForm: FormGroup;
  errors: Array<FieldError> = [];

  constructor(private api: ApiService, private customValidator: CustomValidator, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });
    this.isBusy = false;
  }

  onSubmit(value: any) {
    this.errors = [];
    this.isBusy = true;
    this.api.login(value).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res instanceof ApiError) {
        this.errors = res.error;
        this.isBusy = false;
      } else {
        this.isBusy = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/payment']).then(() => {});

        window.postMessage({
          type: 'LoginSuccess',
          text: 'Login'
        }, '*');
      }
    });
  }

  getErrors(fieldName: string): string {
    const errors = this.signForm.get(fieldName).errors;
    const key = Object.keys(errors)[0];

    return this.customValidator.errorMap[key] ? this.customValidator.errorMap[key] : '';
  }

  checkError(fieldName: string) {
    return !!this.signForm.get(fieldName).errors;
  }
}
```

Comment: Приложите весь лог ошибки

Comment: @Adrug это и есть весь лог

Answer (score -1):

formControlName можно использовать только на инпутах вроде.

Так как у вас formControlName применяется к TextField, скорее всего, вам нужно будет использовать интерфейс CustomValueAccessor. Ну или форму делать через [(ngModel)].